# NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException for Named classes

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I am Using Spring 3.2.2 and was wondering if there was a way to inject beans by class type without explicitly giving them a string name. Ex:

```
@Named
public MyClass{
}

@Named
public MyOtherClass extends MyClass{
}

@Named
public class Foo{
    public void blah(){
       MyClass myClass = context.getBean(MyClass.class);
    }
}
```

This will generate:

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [MyClass] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: myClass,myOtherClass

Is there a way to say "Use the one that matches the class name exactly" without using String names?

In other words I don't want to do:

```
@Named("MyClass")...
@Named("MyOtherClass")...

MyClass myClass = context.getBean("MyClass");
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is what [§ 5.4.5 of Spring manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-exceptions) suggest whenever you encounter non-unique dependency bean definition:

- Abandon autowiring in favor of explicit wiring.
- Avoid autowiring for a bean definition by setting its autowire-candidate attributes to false as described in the next section.
- Designate a single bean definition as the primary candidate by setting the primary attribute of its  element to true.
- If you are using Java 5 or later, implement the more fine-grained control available with annotation-based configuration, as described in [Section 5.9, “Annotation-based container configuration”.](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config)

Answer (score 1):

For the example, you could do something like:

```
@Named
public class Foo{
    public void blah(){
       MyClass myClass = getBean(MyClass.class);
    }

    private <T> T getBean(Class<T> type) {
         return context.getBean(Introspector.decapitalize(type.getSimpleName()), type);
    }
}
```

But this will not work when using `@Inject` or `@Autowire`.

To force strict class matching when autowiring, you could replace the default `AutowireCandidateResolver` on the `BeanFactory` with a `BeanFactoryPostprocessor`, but don't seem a good idea as `@Resource` or `@Qualify` can solve the NUBDE problem.

For example: (Not tested)

```
public class StrictClassAutowireCandidateResolver implements AutowireCandidateResolver {

    @Override
    public boolean isAutowireCandidate(BeanDefinitionHolder bdHolder, DependencyDescriptor descriptor) {
        if (!bdHolder.getBeanDefinition().isAutowireCandidate()) {
            return false;
        }

        if (descriptor == null) {
            return true;
        }

        String className = null;

        if (descriptor.getField() != null) {
            className = descriptor.getField().getType().getName();
        }

        else if (descriptor.getMethodParameter() != null) {
            className = descriptor.getMethodParameter().getParameterType().getName();
        }

        Class<?> clazz = null;
        try {
            clazz = Class.forName(className);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }

        if (clazz.isInterface() || Modifier.isAbstract(clazz.getModifiers())) {
                // have no chances to be strict, let BeanFactory to find implementations.
                return true;
            }

        return bdHolder.getBeanDefinition().getBeanClassName().equals(className);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getSuggestedValue(DependencyDescriptor descriptor) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using @Component (Service, Repository, Controller) on your classes, and @Autowired when you're injecting a bean.

EDIT: my bad, I didn't read the question too well. The problem is that you're actually having 2 instances of MyClass (since MyOtherClass extends from MyClass). Hence there's no other way than giving the classes names, or you'll always end up with NoUniqueBeanDefinitionExceptions.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with @Named? I would prefer to use the JSR standards

Comment: You say you're already using Spring 3.2.2, so why wouldn't you use its annotations?

Comment: I would prefer the JSR annotations so it is easier to switch down the road (if necessary).  There is nothing wrong about using JSR annotations from Spring.  Unless the Spring annotations specifically provide a working solution to this I do not see a valid reason to switch over